# Does anyone tried to run this comparator of XML schemas?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, soa

[http://www.membrane-soa.org/soa-model-doc/1.4/java-api/compare-schema-java-api.html]

I tried but only thing I can get from my schemas is this 
targetNamespace changed from (namespace of schema1) to (namespace of schema2)
And I am using exactly same code and exactly same libraries as package in download section contains. I will be grateful for any advice.

My target is to get what they promise :D

Element createResponse has changed:
 ComplexType  has changed:
  Sequence has changed:
   Element NewElementForTest added.

ComplexType GetAllType has changed:
 Annotation removed.
ect..... ect....

Thanks James :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the tool you refer to is the first time I see it, so take with a grain of salt anything I say about it; after a quick look at the options available to you to compare, I'll venture to guess you have a couple of options here. I would need to explain some things first, considering how I've seen XSD and XML compare work before.

For many tasks, XSDs are reduced to XML or plain text. Your expectation for XSD seems to be rather similar to that seen when comparing two simple XMLs, even though namespaces are different:

[image]

Namespaces are your problem here. In general, a tool comparing XSDs with different target namespaces should not assume anything about global content with the same name; this is because target namespaces can also be used to avoid collisions and refine homonyms (table in furniture vs. table in computing/databases). In your case it seems it is used as a versioning mechanism, since you wish to proceed with comparing entities with the same local name, even though the full qualified names (as qualified by the schema's targetNamespace) are different.

For the API you're using, there doesn't seem to be an option where you could provide a mapping of namespaces (that is for comparison purposes, treat different values the same). I would say, looking at how the report is structured, it is simply because changing namespaces is definitely going to break everything...

Try to manually loop through the list of objects defined by the schema (e.g. [elements](http://www.membrane-soa.org/soa-model/api-doc/1.4/groovydoc/com/predic8/schema/Schema.html#elements), [complex types](http://www.membrane-soa.org/soa-model/api-doc/1.4/groovydoc/com/predic8/schema/Schema.html#complexTypes), etc.), manually match them by their local name (in source/target set), and then call one by one what you can (e.g. for [elements](http://www.membrane-soa.org/soa-model/api-doc/1.4/groovydoc/com/predic8/schema/diff/SchemaDiffGenerator.html#compareElement%28def,%20def,%20def%29)). For complex types you may need to manually traverse their content models.

Another strategy (easier if the XSDs are not that intricate) may be to copy the revision in a temporary location, string-replace the targetNamespace to the old value, and then run with what your tool supports.

Comparing XSDs though is a really complex and interesting subject, if only because what is an "important" change (breaking or not) is a matter of how you're using that XSD. In other words, changing XSDs a certain way would have no impact on an XSLT (XSD aware or not)-based code, while for someone using JAXB-generated classes would be a disaster, while at the same time a .NET consumer would not have to change a single line of code...

[image]

The above shows other conditions, such as "transitive" impact, where changing a base type (Depends Modified) would break code generated from XSD... while the described XML would absolutely be the same.

Comment: I did it a little bit crazy way I am changing it in my Java application these namespaces automaticaly to be same e.g. first xsd NS="first" so I take this and change NS of second XSD to "first" then it works :D. I ll generate it on the side and it works great ;) but thank you for your anwser I found it now by accident. Cheers Jakub